# How to exclude a specific user when deleting all user in Cognito user pool

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cloudshell

I have a script I use to remove all users from a user pool on a regular basis for testing. There is however one user that constantly needs to be manually re-created as it should not get removed when clearing the user pool.
I'm trying to figure out how I can exclude that specific user from the delete. Here is the script I use:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  echo "Deleting $uname1";
  aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" --username $uname1;
done
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Simple shell script enhancement to [compare variable to string](https://superuser.com/questions/543793/how-can-i-compare-a-variable-to-a-text-string-rather-than-integer-in-an-if-els)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your problem makes sense, but like @jarmod commented, what you really want to do here is filter our a specific username before iterating over the `.Username` field `jq` extracts. Your question isn't actually about Cognito at all :) In order to get more and better answers, I'd suggest editing your question to include only the exact problem you're trying to solve, and the code you've tried so far. Then, remove the aws tags and add a `jq` one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`select` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select(boolean_expression)) of jq directly:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" |
jq -r '.Users[].Username | select(. != "excluded username")' |
while read uname1; do
  echo "Deleting $uname1";
  aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" --username $uname1;
done
```

Alternatively, comparing strings in shell is simple too:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  test "$uname1" = "excluded username" || aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" --username $uname1;
done
```

or

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  if [ "$uname1" != "excluded username" ]; then
    aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" --username $uname1;
  fi
done
```

or

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  case "$uname1" in
    "excluded username") ;;
    *) aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id "user-pool-id" --username $uname1 ;;
  esac
done
```